# One of my two linux (ubuntu) drives is gone from boot:

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

(Edit at the end)

I have had a dual boot working for a long time with no problems. Then a couple of weeks ago I decided to dd copy one of them (SSD 256G on /sdb) as backup to a 3rd HDD I had installed to that effect on /sdc and was unused.

Session went fine but when I rebooted the next day, I got straight to the BIOS, where there were no boot options available.

I removed the 3rd drive, same thing.

I enabled CSM and there was only one drive listed, the one I had not copied (SSD 1T on /sda).

I can boot fine from this one but when I try to boot from the other one at grub, I get a black screen. Grub tries to load but gives a signature not signed with trusted key error.

Boot repair and grub see the missing drive, although the bios doesn't.

The content of the drive are intact and I can access it from the functioning drive, so it is a boot issue.

I don't understand why copying a drive to another could have messed up the origin..?

And I'm afraid of doing anything as I really do not want to lose the content on the missing drive.

I usually solve my problems myself by doing some research but this time, I'm stuck and request assistance...

I attach the boot repair log, in case it contains useful info and a pic of my grub customizer. I can provide anything required.
Thanks!

[Boot-Repair](https://filebin.net/k0y5fagplzo3d62d/Boot-Info_20200220_1639.txt?t=xdb57730)
[grub](https://filebin.net/k0y5fagplzo3d62d/Screenshot_from_2020-02-20_17-10-59.png?t=xdb57730)

#

nick@XP11:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 860 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ext4         boot

Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  222GB  222GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      222GB   256GB  34.3GB  extended
 5      222GB   256GB  34.3GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)

#

I used "dd if=dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=64k conv=sync , noerror status=progress" To the best of my recollection.

And @guiverc: That's what I immediately thought so I disconnected the copied-to disk. It's still off.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please advise what exactly which command with all options and switches you used to _dd copy one of them (SSD 256G on /sdb) as backup to a 3rd HDD_. Please also run `sudo parted -l` in Ubuntu, then copy the result, return here, click [edit], and paste the result into your question so we may better understand your system.

Comment: If you cloned a drive; the clone will likely have the same UUIDs as the original drive and thus if both drives are installed at boot on the same box at the same time, the box may ignore both drives (two UUIDs shouldn't exist so it's undefined what should occur, ignoring them all is reasonable, as could be ignoring one drive). It could be I missed something from your description too.

Comment: I decided to rsync  the file system to the functioning drive, reinstall 18.04 on the offending one and rsynced back to the new install. Now I have UUID issues but that's another problem... Thanks for responding to my initial distress call!